# Teams Meet Now option progmatically

Tags: automation, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams-->Calander you have an option Meet Now which starts a meeting instanctly. Later you can share the link or add people into this.

Is there any way to automate this? I mean I am looking for Powershell script or batch file which will start the meeting.

I am literally tired to click multiple times to to start a meeting.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to start a meeting instantly (As via option 'Meet Now') programmatically.  To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).